# get the current page TabId/ModuleId in DNN Razor script host

Tags: dotnetnuke, dnn9

We have several DNN (latest version) pages using the Razor script host module (shared), configured to the same cshtml file. The script pulls in some external content which has always been the same on each page. Now, we need the content to be contextual to each page. I don't see a way to add a config input to the script host and I'd prefer to avoid a separate script for each page.

Is there a way to get the TabId, ModuleId, page name, or some other other identifying value in the script? We have other Razor pages that reference `DotNetNuke.UI.Modules.ModuleInstanceContext` and use the `TabId` or `ModuleId` but I'm not seeing a way to get an instance in this context.

Comment: It turned out to be as easy as I expected: `Dnn.Tab.TabID` etc.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend that you switch from the RazorHost module to 2sxc.  You will be able to reuse your cshtml files, but you'll also get much, much more.

I think that lots of DNN variables are available in RazorHost, but it's been years since I have used it.  You might find info by Googling.  Look for dnnHelper.

But ... ignore that and go directly to 2sxc.  Do not pass go!